# MS Access show current users not showing username

Tags: database, ms-access, vba

I'm currently using a piece of code to display who is logged into our Access Database. It's a split database, with a backend and multiple frontends. I am currently using this code:

```
Private Sub btnShowUsers_Click()
'The User List Schema information requires this magic number. For anyone
'who may be interested, this number is called a GUID or Globally Unique
'Identifier - sorry for digressing
Const conUsers = "{947bb102-5d43-11d1-bdbf-00c04fb92675}"

Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection, fld As ADODB.Field, strUser As String
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset, intUser As Integer, varValue As Variant

Set cnn = CurrentProject.Connection
Set rst = cnn.OpenSchema(Schema:=adSchemaProviderSpecific, SchemaID:=conUsers)

'Set List Box Heading
strUser = "Computer;UserName;Connected?;Suspect?"
Debug.Print rst.GetString

With rst    'fills Recordset (rst) with User List data
  Do Until .EOF
    intUser = intUser + 1
      For Each fld In .Fields
        varValue = fld.Value
          'Some of the return values are Null-Terminated Strings, if
          'so strip them off
          If InStr(varValue, vbNullChar) > 0 Then
            varValue = Left(varValue, InStr(varValue, vbNullChar) - 1)
          End If
          strUser = strUser & ";" & varValue
      Next
        .MoveNext
  Loop
End With

Me!txtTotalNumOfUsers = intUser        'Total # of Users

'Set up List Box Parameters
Me!lstUsers.ColumnCount = 4
Me!lstUsers.RowSourceType = "Value List"
Me!lstUsers.ColumnHeads = False
  lstUsers.RowSource = strUser       'populate the List Box

'Routine cleanup chores
Set fld = Nothing
Set rst = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing

End Sub
```

This works, and it returns the laptop numbers of the users currently using the system, but in the 'Username' column it just says 'ADMIN'. Is there any way to get this to show their Windows username, ie their VBA.Environ("USERNAME")?

Comment: Sorry - that must have been from a previous draft. Title updated.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible.

This column shows the Access username, same as the `Application.CurrentUser()` method.

Unless you set up user-level security, add all users to the workgroup file, and start Access with a command-line parameter like

```
 /User %username%
```

, the user name will always be "Admin".